# Micropython with PN532 V3 Elechouse

Tags: microcontroller, esp32, micropython, adafruit-circuitpython

I have a ESP32S with micropython installed and I have a PN532 from Elechouse to read NFC tags. Is there any possible way to combine these two together?

I've only found information about Adafruit PN532 NFC/RFID Breakout and PN532 NFC/RFID Shield on CircuitPython. I tried using the CircuitPython  libraries but I got an error `ImportError: no module named 'busio'` when trying to run it.

To do so, I installed the Adafruit bundle for CircuitPython following this https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_Bundle and the instructions that are linked on this repo.

Comment: Finally got an anwser on the only youtube video talking about it. Someone took the job of doing all the merging from CPython to MicroPython. Link to his YouTube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NuVhXdyeZvQ&t=1171s Link to the GitHub repo:
https://github.com/somervda/nfc-tester/tree/ed166545357cde894f40cee2de3e44fc15592dfe